# Do we have any command that HDFS rm/rmr command confirmation before removing the file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rm

If I call **hdfs dfs -rm -r Filepath**, the file/directory will delete instantly.

I want to know whether any command arguments is there which will ask for confirmation before rm the files?

Answer (score 0):

It's not deleted immediately unless you add the skipTrash flag option

The documentation covers that and all other options, none of which include user prompt/validation, so you would need to write your own wrapper script to do that